# unexpected symbol error when doing group_by with 2 variables in dplyr

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I have two categorical variables and a numeric one. I want to first group by "Regional Manager" and then within each Regional Manager, I want to sum the total Opportunity figure for each Firm, before finding out the top 5 firms for each Regional Manager. The following code gave me the error message

> Error in parse(text = x) : :1:10: unexpected symbol 1: Regional
>   Manager

```
raw %>% 
  group_by(.dots=c('Regional Manager','Firm')) %>% 
  summarize(Total = sum(Opportunity)) %>% 
  top_n(5)
```

Comment: `group_by` takes bare column names. Try `raw %>% group_by(\`Regional Manager\`, Firm)`

Comment: It's also better to work with legal column names if you can. For example, even though its easiest to use `group_by` with bare column names, your code would actually have worked if `Regional Manager` were a legal name, like `Regional_Manager` (meaning it doesn't have to be enclosed in backticks) or if you enclosed `Regional Manager` in backticks inside the quotation marks (`group_by(.dots=c("\`Regional Manager\`",'Firm'))`).